# I found the PDE solution

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

I found the PDE solution:

$$u_t+u_x=u^2$$
$$u(0,x)=\cos(x)$$

The solution is:

$$u(t,x)=\frac{\cos(x-t)}{1-t\cos(x-t)}$$

Now how do you find the lowest $ t $ to which the solution "explodes" and which point it "explodes". I tried to parse when $t\cos(x-t)$ tends $1$, but I could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Write $x=r+t$ and put $f(r,t) = \tfrac{\cos r}{1-t\cos r}$. Then $f$ "explodes" when $1-t\cos r = 0$, i.e., when $\cos r = \tfrac1t$. You can write $u$ in terms of $f$.

Comment: I thought the following: $1-tcos(r)=0 \Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{cos(r)}$ for $cos(r) \neq 0$. therefore $t$ is minimal when $cos (r)$ is maximum, so $t = 1$ is this right?

Comment: The point where it "explodes" would be $(1,1)$

Comment: @Lucas : It explodes along the entire curve defined by $1-t\cos r=0$, which can be written $t = \sec r$.